# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types' in apk

Tags: python, cryptography, kivy, apk, buildozer

I'm trying to make a python application for android using opencv and OPC UA (asyncua). The basis for me is camera4kivy (https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Camera4Kivy). When running the application on phone (AndroidStudio - emulator) I got an error as in the topic. In buildozer.spec in the requirements line I have:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.2.1,dateutil==2.8.1,camera4kivy,gestures4kivy,opencv,pyOpenSSL,wheel==0.42.0,cryptography==41.0.7,asyncua,typing_extensions,requests,aiofiles,certifi,urllib3
```

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types import PrivateKeyTypes
```

The error is in the Client.py (asyncua), I thought that if I move the import to another place I will get more information, but it didn't help. It is currently in main.py at the very beginning, but this error is also generated. I don't have any more ideas :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used an earlier versions of asyncua (1.0.4) not 1.0.6. There is no `from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types import PrivateKeyTypes`